# Plot maximum and minimum temperature of a day for range of time interval

Tags: plotting, functions

How to display (in any graphic representation) the maximum and minimum temperatures for one city in one of these selected time periods over the 5-day period?  The time periods are:

- Morning (06:00 to 12:00)
- Afternoon (12:00 to 16:00)
- Evening (16:00 to 20:00)
- Night (20:00 to 06:00 the next day).

I'd like the x-axis to show the date and the y-axis to show temperatures.

I already wrote a small bit of code which can find the mean in a given time interval

```
Mean[Select[
  Flatten[
   WeatherData[
    "Your_City_Name", 
    "Temperature", {{2012, 11, 5, 6, 0}, {2012, 11, 5, 12, 0}}]
   , 1], NumberQ
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears `WeatherData` does not provide max and min temperatures on a smaller timescale than daily.

```
londoncoordinates = CityData["London", "Coordinates"];
londonweatherstation = WeatherData[londoncoordinates, "NearestStation"];

DateListPlot[{
  {DatePlus[#1, {12, "Hour"}], #2} & @@@ 
   WeatherData[londonweatherstation,
    "MinTemperature", {{2012, 11, 5}, {2012, 11, 10}, "Day"}],
  {DatePlus[#1, {12, "Hour"}], #2} & @@@ 
   WeatherData[londonweatherstation,
    "MaxTemperature", {{2012, 11, 5}, {2012, 11, 10}, "Day"}],
  WeatherData[londonweatherstation, "Temperature",
   {{2012, 11, 5, 6, 0}, {2012, 11, 10, 6, 0}}]}, Joined -> True,
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightYellow}}]
```

[image]